# How to set up data collection for small-scale algorithmic trading software

Tags: python, database, algorithmic-trading

This is a question on a conceptual level.

I'm building a piece of small-scale algorithmic trading software, and I am wondering how I should set up the data collection/retrieval within that system. The system should be fully autonomous.

Currently my algorithm that I want to trade live is doing so on a very low frequency, however I would like to be able to trade with higher frequency in the future and therefore I think that it would be a good idea to set up the data collection using a websocket to get real time trades straight away. I can aggregate these later if need be.

My first question is: considering the fact that the data will be real time, can I use a CSV-file for storage in the beginning, or would you recommend something more substantial?

In any case, the data collection would proceed as a daemon in my application.

My second question is: are there any frameworks available to handle real-time incoming data to keep the database constant while the rest of the software is querying it to avoid conflicts?

My third and final question is: do you believe it is a wise approach to use a websocket in this case or would it be better to query every time data is needed for the application?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

CSV is a nice exchange format, but as it is based on a text file, it is not good for real-time updates. Only my opinion but I cannot imagine a reason to prefere that to database.

In order to handle real time conflicts, you will later need a professional grade database. PostgreSQL has the reputation of being robust, MariaDB is probably a correct choice too. You could use a liter database in development mode like SQLite, but beware of the slight differences: it is easy to write something that will work on one database and will break on another one. On another hand, if portability across databases is important, you should use at least 2 databases: one at development time and a different one at integration time.

A question to ask yourself immediately is whether you want a relational database or a noSQL one. Former ensures ACID (Atomicity, Consistency, Isolation, Durability) transations, the latter offers greater scalability.

Comment: Thank you. Would you believe it to be feasible to keep the live data in ram for 10 minutes, then clearing it and updating a CSV-file? I'm not by any stretch of the imagination an expert in databases and would like to get the program up and running quickly, the investigation you are suggesting sounds time-consuming. Obviously, I will need to dig into databases later if it picks up some speed

Comment: @ThéodoreMontel: The problem with a CSV file is that you have to write the full file at once. I know neither the final platform nor the data volume, nor the throughput so I cannot say more. But IMHO, you should dig into relational and noSQL databases before going further or ask someone knowing about them when you are a little more advanced.

Comment: I understand. Thank you for your answers!

Answer (score 0):

Man Group, one of the major players in algo-trading, have open sourced their data store called Artic, designed specifically for time series and tick data. You can find it [here](https://github.com/manahl/arctic).

Comment: That is a very good option. Thank you for the recommendation.

Comment: I don't have enough reputation for the upvotes to show.